# MySQL - combining two records, different fields from each record

Tags: mysql, merge, selection, records

I am updating an existing database to simplify it and extend its functionality.  I have a table as follows:

```
ID  Parent  increment     info 1    info 2
1   103        0            25        1
2   103        1             4        2
3   103        2            45        5
4   103        3            13        7
5   115        0            17        5
6   115        1            23        3
7   116        0            22        2
8   116        1            1         1
9   116        2            7         3
10  117        0            19        4
```

I want the new table to contain only one record for each "parent" and that record should contain for most fields, the data from the record with that parent number which has the maximum 'increment' number, but for the info 2 field it should comtain the data from the record wth the minimum 'increment'.

The desired output is as follows:

```
ID  Parent  increment   info 1  info 2
4   103        3        13         1
6   115        1        23         5
9   116        2        7          2
10  117        0        19         4
```

Is this sort of selective merging of records possible in Mysql?

I have looked at using Group by Parent, but there are a fair number of fields to bring over, so I'm not sure that will work.  I've also looked at a LEFT OUTER JOIN of the table to itself to highlight the record within each parent with the maximum increment, but that doesnt allow me to select the data fro the record with the same parent but the minimum increment.

Stumped and would really appreciate someone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tt1.ID, tt1.Parent, MaxInc, tt1.info1, tt2.info2 FROM 
(SELECT ID, Parent, MaxInc, info1 FROM test INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Parent AS p, MAX(incr) AS MaxInc FROM test GROUP BY Parent) AS t1 
ON Parent = p AND incr = MaxInc) AS tt1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT Parent, info2 FROM test INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Parent AS p, MIN(incr) AS MinInc FROM test GROUP BY Parent) AS t2 
ON Parent = p AND incr = MinInc) AS tt2 ON tt1.Parent = tt2.Parent
```

I changed increment to incr

Comment: fantastic.  works like a dream.  I'm a newbie here but would def vote this answer up, w770115, otherwise.

Comment: I am also trying to apply same query to ms-access mdf file but keep getting join error. Any thoughts?

Comment: In MS Access sub queries must be done in different query and then you can inner join to this query.
Here:

Comment: In MS Access sub queries must be done in different query and then you can inner join to this query.
Here:
This would be first query:
SELECT Parent AS p, MAX(incr) AS MaxInc FROM test GROUP BY Parent
Save it for example query1

Second query - query2:
SELECT Parent AS p, MIN(incr) AS MinInc FROM test GROUP BY Parent

Comment: Third one - query3:
SELECT ID, Parent, MaxInc, info1 FROM test INNER JOIN query1 AS t1 ON Parent = p AND incr = MaxInc

The forth - query4:
SELECT Parent, info2 FROM test INNER JOIN query2 AS t2 ON Parent = p AND incr = MinInc

And the last one:
SELECT tt1.ID, tt1.Parent, MaxInc, tt1.info1, tt2.info2 FROM query3 AS tt1 INNER JOIN query4 AS tt2 ON tt1.Parent = tt2.Parent

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this.  Assuming that you have only the values from 1 to 9 in the additional field:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select left(parent, locate(' ', parent) - 1) as p,
             MAX(parent) as maxparent,
             max(len
      from t
      group by left(parent, locate(' ', parent))
     ) tp
     on left(t.parent, locate(' ', t.parent) - 1) = tp.p
where t.parent = tp.maxparent
```

If the numbers go beyond 9, you need some additional fiddling, such as:

```
select *
from t join
     (select left(parent, locate(' ', parent) - 1) as p,
             max(SUBSTRING(parent, locate(' ', parent) + 1)) as maxval
      from t
      group by left(parent, locate(' ', parent))
     ) tp
     on left(t.parent, locate(' ', t.parent) - 1) = tp.p
where t.parent = concate(tp.p, ' ', maxval)
```

With the revised data structure:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select parent, MAX(increment) as maxi
      from t
      group by parent
     ) tp
     on t.parent = tp.parent and t.increment = tp.maxi
```

Comment: thanks for the amazingly quick response.  I'll have a play with it and report back.

Comment: is the locate(' ', parent) -1) language necessary? my table layout wasn't very clear.  ive tidied it up a bit.

Comment: @TimCullen . .. No, and that much simplifies the problem.  See the final answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  This succesfully selects the record for each 'parent' which has the highest increment.  But I want to combine some fields from that record with some fields from the record with the minimum increment for that 'parent'